# How to get multi users login in scrapy data extraction?

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy

I have successfully extract data for single user login to the website but my requirement is to make the scrapy script to work for multiple users(generally 5000 users login at same time) to pass as list and make data extraction for each users and export the extracted data into csv format.
Here is the code i have try it for single user login:

```
import scrapy
import csv

username = 'abc'
password = 'xyz'

class GiffgafSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'giffgaf'
    allowed_domains = ['www.something.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.something.com/auth/login']
    output = "output.csv"

    def __init__(self):
        open(self.output,"w").close()

    def parse(self, response):
        token = response.xpath('.//*[@name="form_key"]/@value').extract_first()
        yield scrapy.FormRequest('https://www.something.com/auth/login',formdata={'form_key':token,'username': username,'password':password},callback=self.startscraping)

    def startscraping(self,response):
        yield scrapy.Request('https://www.giffgaff.com/dashboard',callback=self.verifylogin)

    def verifylogin(self,response):

        with open(self.output,"a",newline="") as f:
            writer = csv.writer(f)
            phonenumber = response.css("h2.profile-phone-number::text").extract_first()
            writer.writerow([nickname,password,phonenumber])
            yield {'uname':username,'password':password,'phone':phonenumber}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Voting to close as **Too Broad** . Stackoverflow is dedicated to helping solve programming code problems (not design or scalability issues, unless presented as code that is not working). . Please read [Help On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic) and [Help How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/How-to-ask) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Comment: Ok i will update my question with code problem.

Comment: You're asking for high level consulting and problem solving for a project. You need to make your Qs really specific about "why isn't my code working". Also see [mcve] for definitions of appropriate S.O. questions. Good luck.